# Clean GCD queue for all the rest requests in queue

Tags: ios, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch

I have a cache of files in which I need to write/read images.

All the work with the file system I need to perform in background.

For this purposes for saving files I use:

```
dispatch_barrier_async([AxPanoramaDataManager sharedInstance].dataManagerQueue, ^{
    [data writeToFile:tileFilePathName atomically:YES];
});
```

And for reading:

```
    __block UIImage *tileImage = nil;
    dispatch_sync([AxPanoramaDataManager sharedInstance].dataManagerQueue, ^{
        tileImage = [[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:tileFilePathName] retain];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            completion (tileCoordValue, side, tileImage, error);
            [tileImage release];
        });
    });
```

Everything works well, there is a great amount of files in cash folder, but I sometimes I need to clean the cash. I need to cancel all the queue blocks and perform a block with cleaning the folder.

The first my realization of the method looks like this:

```
+ (void) cleanCash
{
    NSString *folderPath = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingString:@"cash"];
    dispatch_sync([AxPanoramaDataManager sharedInstance].dataManagerQueue, ^{
        NSError *error = nil;
            [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:folderPath error:&error];
            NSParameterAssert(error == nil);
        }
    });
}
```

But I have a numerous problems with it because of it is not cancel the all the waiting operations in queue. I try to look solutions in SO but can't implement them unfortunately. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Don't you mean 'cache' instead of 'cash' ?

Comment: Yes, sorry En is not my native language

Comment: No worries, neither is it mine :)  I thought it was a funny typo!

Answer (score 0):

You can use NSOperationQueue with maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1 (it will make a serial queue) for run NSOperation that will load your images;
NSOperation is a cancelable object. Also you can make dependencies between operations.

P.S.
You can view SDWebImage, it contains SDImageCache class. It class is very good for manage cache of images.

Comment: This deserves elaboration; Once submitted to a GCD queue, the blocks are not inherently cancelable. If you want cancelation behavior, you have to build that into your block by having them check some outside state to determine if they should return immediately or proceed with their work. `NSOperation` and `NSOperationQueue` are higher level abstractions that have this cancelation behavior built in.